Can a ex spouse collect half of equity after sale of home?
My ex is part of the mortgage but has not contributed anything towards the payment since we moved here in 2021. Does she have the right to collect half of the equity when the house is sold?

We are friends and have lived together since the divorce. But in separate rooms.
Her income from SS is very small. I give her a good share of my retirement. I still pay the mortgage plus all the utilities and other bills, she does not contribute one dollar to help. Plus have promised her to give her more after the sale of the house. She does pay for most of the food, I do share some of the cost of that. She did spend some of her own money on the backyard.

Let me add a little more to this I am retired military and she is trying to get half of my entire retirement. She said she has talked to a lawyer and he said she deserves more. Legally she can get 50% of my military retirement pay. Which she gets more than that now.
My feeling on this since she has not paid for anything towards the house she doesn’t have the right legally to collect half of the equity.
Thanks

Country? And state if in the US?

If you were married and now divorced, the divorce decree would be the single most important element to resolving the question.  That should specify who was awarded what percentage of ownership of the home after the divorce.

We did not use a lawyer we did it through a service. Because we were married for 45 years when we got divorced; we were left to make our own decisions about things. She gets more of my military pension than she is suppose to receive. But since she is trying to get more money from me I felt she should not get any money from the sale of the house. I will say that I have consulted a lawyer to ask those questions, since I posted here. Waiting on a response from them in the morning.

@WillyWilson it sounds like you goofed yourself by not using a lawyer.  You may want to see one now to see if anything can be undone.


My ex is part of the mortgage but has not contributed anything towards the payment since we moved here in 2021. Does she have the right to collect half of the equity when the house is sold?

It doesn't matter whether she's on the mortgage, what matters is whether she's on the title/deed. Does she have an ownership interest in the property?

We are friends and have lived together since the divorce. But in separate rooms.

This may suggest she has ownership interest, unless there's a rental agreement in place.

Her income from SS is very small. I give her a good share of my retirement. I still pay the mortgage plus all the utilities and other bills, she does not contribute one dollar to help. Plus have promised her to give her more after the sale of the house. She does pay for most of the food, I do share some of the cost of that. She did spend some of her own money on the backyard.

This doesn't seem relevant at all, other than an existence of some kind of post-sale entitlement for equity that you're suggesting here. Again, may be a hint for ownership interest.

My feeling on this since she has not paid for anything towards the house she doesn’t have the right legally to collect half of the equity.

Your feelings are not relevant to the question of legal rights.

She said she has talked to a lawyer

Good idea. I suggest you do too. Preferably a different one.
